# Android: Does Custom View have startService

Tags: android, android-intent, android-intentservice

I am having a Custom View which uploading image to the server when clicked.

I get the context using getContext and use it to call start the intent service. Somehow the service didn't get started when I make a checkpoint at the onHandleIntent or onStartCommand. I have placed a reference in the manifest.

This is the code call to service in which the code was inside the Custom View which extending the ImageView:

```
new GraphicUtilitiesV2.SimpleImageLoadingCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void imageAvailable(Object sender, String data) {

                                        if (_formCOC != null && _formType != null) {
                                            Gson gson = new Gson();
                                            String formCOC = gson.toJson(_formCOC);
                                            UploadAttachmentService.startActionAttachmentDeclarative
                                                    (getContext(), formCOC, _formType.getValue(), data);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
```

This is my demo code of the AttachmentUploadService class :

```
private static final String ACTION_DECLARATIVE = "blah.Service.action.DeclarativeAttachment";

private static final String EXTRA_FORM = "blah.CERTIFI.Service.extra.Form";
private static final String EXTRA_TYPE = "blah.Service.extra.FormType";
private static final String EXTRA_DATA = "blah.Service.extra.Data";

public static void startActionAttachmentDeclarative(Context context, String form, String type, String data) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, UploadAttachmentService.class);
    intent.setAction(ACTION_DECLARATIVE);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_FORM, form);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TYPE, type);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, data);
    context.startService(intent);
}

public UploadAttachmentService() {
    super("UploadService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (intent != null) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ACTION_DECLARATIVE.equals(action)) {
            final String param1 = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_FORM);
            final String param2 = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_DATA);
            handleActionAttachmentDeclarative(param1, param2);
        }
    }
}

public void handleActionAttachmentDeclarative(String form, String data) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(50000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

There are no error or force close as well.

This is my manifest part:

```
<service
        android:name=".Service.UploadAttachmentService"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>
```

The UploadAttachmentService file was stored in a Service folder.

Comment: Ok but the code came from the same class which auto generated by the android studio. I modified certain part to suit my need

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble understand your code. I can't help. Hopefully, someone else can understand it.